# UIStoryboardSegue cannot be performed a second time

Tags: swift, segue

I'm trying to switch from the inefficient transitions in my application(in which views are stacked on top of each other and never dismissed) to efficient ones in which views are dismissed when I'm done with them.

In this specific case, I have my Root View Controller which opens a Settings View Controller. When I exit Settings, I can reload the Root View properly to reflect any changes made in the Settings. The issue takes place when I try to 
**reopen** the Settings View Controller. My IBAction is run and I get the print statement from it, but the View is not shown.

Why is it shown the first time, but not the second?

I've tried a few variations of reloading the View Controller. The View is reloading in the way I want it to but it's just not opening that Settings View the second time around.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if didOpenFromSettings == true {
             reloadViewFromNib()
             loadTheView() //Runs the same actions as viewDidLoad()

             collectionView.reloadData()

     }
}

@IBAction func settingsButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("User attempted to enter settings menu.")

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Settings View", sender: self)
}
```

Here's what the Settings Exit process looks like:

```
@IBAction func settingsExitButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

//  This is used to let the Root View know to only reload itself 
//  when coming from the settings.
    didOpenFromSettings = true


}
```

Comment: Just to clarify you are definitely using an unwind segue to dismiss the SettingsViewController? Meaning you have an 
@IBAction func unwindToRoot(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {} function in your RootViewController?

Comment: @CameronPorter No, I was using dismiss(animated, completion)

Comment: can you provide more code for both viewcontrollers?  dismiss(animated...) should work unless you're also calling something.

Comment: @AlexBailey Sorry for the delay, went to bed shortly after posting. Updated the post with the IBAction function for the Settings View's exit button.


Edit: Should that didOpenFromSettings be above the dismissal? I'll move that and see if it fixes anything.

---Nope, no change.